# Нарисовать Ellipse под курсором мыши по центру. Не работает при смещении координат

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-canvas

Необходимо расположить точку для рисования под курсором, где острый край мыши находится по центру. При таком варианте точки на холсте не отрисовываются. Если установить без смещения, то всё работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 public void DrawPoint(Point point, Canvas canvas)
    {
        Ellipse el = new Ellipse();
        el.Width = 10;
        el.Height = 10;
        el.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, point.X);
        el.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, point.Y);
        el.Fill = Brushes.Red;

        // Добавление графического элемента на холст.
        canvas.Children.Add(el);
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point point = e.GetPosition(Canvas);
        point.Offset(-5.0, -5.0);

        DrawPoint(point, Canvas);
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Canvas.Children.Count !=0)
        {
            Canvas.Children.RemoveAt(Canvas.Children.Count - 1);
        }
        Point point = e.GetPosition(Canvas);
        point.Offset(-5.0, -5.0);
        DrawPoint(point, Canvas);
    }
```

---

```
<Canvas  
MouseMove="ContentPanel_MouseMove" 
MouseEnter="ContentPanel_MouseEnter" 
MouseLeave="ContentPanel_MouseLeave"  
MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
x:Name="Canvas" 
Margin="0,10,0,0" 
Panel.ZIndex="998" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: `InkCanvas` позволяет рисовать на себе мышкой вообще из коробки. Попробуйте. Кажется, этот велосипед уже изобрели. А так, не понятно, почему не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что когда вы сдвигаете эллипс, то коодинаты мыши оказываются над эллипсом, и клик проходит именно в эллипс, а не в канвас. Вследствие чего обработчик `Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown` вообще не вызывается. Да, `Ellipse` - это полноценный контрол, а не просто рисунок. Он тоже может обрабатывать клики по себе.

Чтобы это исправить, надо добавить прозрачность для кликабельности создаваемому эллипсу.

```cs
el.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```